# QTreeWidget turn off selection

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreewidget

By default a `QTreeWidget` manages the selection of rows (*when you click a row it highlights it, when you click another row it highlights that and deselects the previous row*),  I don't want this and cant figure out how to turn it off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [`setSelectionMode`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop) of the `QAbstractItemView` class (which `QTreeWidget` is inherited from) to set no selection mode to the component. Something like this (sorry, code in C++):

```cpp
yourtreeView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

In this case items would not get selected but you still will see focus rectangle around them. To fix this you can set your widget to not accept focus by calling:

```
yourtreeView->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

if your tree widget has to accept focus but should not be drawing focus rectangles you can use custom item delegate and remove `State_HasFocus` state from the item's state before drawing it. Something like this:

```
class NoFocusDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;
};

void NoFocusDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);
    if (itemOption.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus)
        itemOption.state = itemOption.state ^ QStyle::State_HasFocus;
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
}

....

NoFocusDelegate* delegate = new NoFocusDelegate();
yourtreeView->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got lost with setSelectionModel(), didnt think i'd find the answer in QAbstractItemView thats fo sure, thanks Serge.

Comment: Thank you and the questioner, pyqt version is: yourtreeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
yourtreeView.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the answer above, I think the Python version is (^ ^):

```
yourtreeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
yourtreeView.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```